# FindBugs: overridden equals() causing static code analysis error EQ_CHECK_FOR_OPERAND_NOT_COMPATIBLE_WITH_THIS

Tags: java, overriding, equals, findbugs

I am getting FindBugs error that I am confused how to fix. Since this is old, legacy code, I can not do much about it. `equals()` implementation, not perfect but doing its job,  but shows error at static code analysis.

**FindBugs Error:**

> EQ_CHECK_FOR_OPERAND_NOT_COMPATIBLE_WITH_THIS Equals checks for
>   incompatible operand

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

I did make couple of tweaks but could not prevent this error.

```
class Account extends ManagedAccount{

    String accountId;
    public void setAccount(EntityId value) {
        //some setter
    }
    void EntityId getAccountId() {
        return EntityId;//EntityId is some class
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Account) {
            if (this.getAccountId().equals(o))) {
                return super.equals(o);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `accountId` is confusing as a) it's not used here and b) `getAccountId` returns some other `EntityId` field.

Answer (score 1):

Probably FindBugs triggers at third line of your `equals` method:

```
if (this.getAccountId().equals(o)))
```

There is something strange here. You compare `this.getAccountId()` with entire object `o`.

Just fix this line and everything should be fine.

Comment: To clarify, you're comparing an `Account` instance (`o`) with `this`'s `EntityId` field (name of a class?), a very strange thing to do. It should probably be `if (this.getAccountId().equals(((Account) o).getAccountId()))` though I still don't get the `accountId`/`EntityId` dichotomy.